# asp.net regular exprssion Max char with not in condition

Tags: asp.net

I have my regular expression as ValidationExpression="^[^<>]*$"
I want to add number of char it will accept. 
say for example i want to  limit my textbox(multiline) length to 200.
how to achieve.
I tried  ValidationExpression="^[^<>]*{0, 200}$" but its not working.
what is the solution>

Comment: Could you clarify "not working"? What happens exactly when you try this, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message?

Comment: Can you please show your controller code for the `<TextBox />`  and the `<RegularExpressionValidator />` ?

Comment: "Not working"  I mean it is not taking any cherector..

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtdesc" runat="server" Width="150px" Onkeypress="return check(event)" TextMode="MultiLine"
                            MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>                   and the regular exp is                 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtdesc"
                            ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="These characters <> are allowed." ValidationExpression="^[^<>]{0, 10}$" />

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit your string length to max 200 characters (accepting ANY character) do this:

```
ValidationExpression="^.{0,200}$"
```

EDIT:
Sorry, I think I see what you meant before an why it didn't work. Try this instead:

```
ValidationExpression="^[^&lt;&gt;]{0,200}$"
```